# Error trying to install the Java SDK

Tags: 11.10, java

I need to install the Java 6 SDK, but after running this:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-jre sun-java6-source
```

I end up with this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
sun-java6-jdk : Depends: sun-java6-bin (>= 6.26-1lucid1) but it is not going to be                   installed
sun-java6-jre : Depends: sun-java6-bin (>= 6.26-1lucid1) but it is not going to be  installed or
ia32-sun-java6-bin (>= 6.26-1lucid1) but it is not installable
Recommends: gsfonts-x11 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and need the packages for my course. I guess they've become corrupted but, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It is saying that it doesn't have sun-java6-bin, which is a dependency, so install that too. Modify your original command to:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-jre sun-java6-source sun-java6-bin
```